# Find/Replace Double Quotes using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to use the Field Calculator (ArcMap 10.0) to strip out double quotes in an address field (I didn't put them in there, believe me).  I've tried many incantations but am still unable to even get off the ground with a calculation. yes, both fields are string, and both are of acceptable length.

This calculation:
[image: Sample calculation]

Results in this:

[image: fail]

With this error message in the Results dialog:

[image: error message]

And I repeat, I didn't put them in there.

Comment: So you're copying them with the quotes in your test, did you already attempt stripping the quotes with something like `!testing![1:len(!testing!)-1]`

Comment: The snippet you provided dies with the same message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found that in 10.0 Field Calculator is quite weird.

But I've managed to get it work. The main idea is to enclose field name with single quotes.

**Example.** let suppose we have fields `text1` and `text2`. Rather than Calculating field `text2` with expression `!text1!`, which probably will fail, try this one: `'!text1'`. As you see I am using single quotes here.

So, back to your task. It will be more clear to use Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def calc(value):
    return value.replace('"', '')
```

Expression will be:

```
calc('!text1!')
```

I hope it will work for you.

I have not experimented further but I think that such weird behavior happens because field calculation is translated into the call to ArcToolbox tool `CalculateField_management` and expression is provided as a parameter to it (probably additionally enclosed with single or double quotes).

**UPDATE:**

My previous solution will fail in case if there are single quotes in the values of field `text1`.

Now I have managed to get it work both in case when there are chars `'` and `"` (single and double quotes) inside any value in attribute `text1`.

Here is expression, which will return original string, supporting both types of quotes:

```
'''!text1!'''[1:-1]
```

For your task it can be extended to (without Pre-Logic Script Code):

```
'''!text1!'''[1:-1].replace('"', '')
```

Comment: Well, you got my hopes up, but that doesn't work for me. Neither the codeblock nor the straight up `'!testing!'`

Comment: Hm, it worked on my 10.0sp4. May be it is because somewhere in your field there is actually single quote... Have you considered using UpdateCursor in python script?

Comment: You know what? you're right, it does work. I hadn't had my 3:00 wake up juice. You win.

Comment: I have managed to solve problem with a single quote. Check my update to the answer.

Comment: The Pre-Logic Script Code worked fine when used within a script - many thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you are using version 10.1 and you are sure you want to get rid of every instance of double quotes you can use:

```
!testing!.replace("\"","")
```

If anyone knows why this works in 10.1 and not 10.0 I would be interested.

Here are the results entry from my run.

[image]

Comment: What is the magic trick here, your script did not work?

Comment: This doesn't work.  It looks like it should, but it doesn't.

Comment: Both of your fields are text correct?

Comment: @Gus, Yes field is text.

Comment: Are you using 10.0?

Comment: Very interesting. It works in 10.1 but not in 10.0. Never saw that coming.

Comment: @Gus, You may want to update your answer to direct solution via 10.1.

Comment: I am not using 10.1. I am using 10.0 - that archaic version that is sooooo 2011.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but does using "&quot;" in place of "\"" for v10 give the same error?

Comment: Nope, just tested it. `!testing!.replace("&quot;","")` does not work.

Comment: @valveLondon try `!testing!.replace('"','')`

Comment: @Mike - nope, all the standard Python methods fail...

Answer (score 8):

Here is a non script way to do it.

1. Start edit session on you layer.
2. Open up table and highlight field column.
3. Select Table Options drop down arrow and select Find & Replace.
4. Select Replace tab and enter Find what: `"`, select Replace all (you will have to click the Replace All button twice).

Comment: while I appreciate the possibility, I'm not only wanting to replace the double quotes and I'd rather work via scripting.

Answer (score 3):

A hybrid approach worked on my system:

```
'!testing!'.replace("\"","")
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this inside of Arc, but I was able to remove double quotes from a string in a Python IDE in this (quick) way:

```
aStr ='"test"'

a1 = aStr.lstrip('"')
a2 = a1.rstrip('"')

print a2
```

a2 prints test, without quotes.

Comment: I realize this doesn't help with the 'Find' portion of your question...

Answer (score 0):

hi try using single quotes like this !test!.replace('"','')

Comment: Hi, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found it pretty easy with the old VBScript Function: `Replace ([testing],"""","")`